# Как разрешить доступ всем ролям ко всем действиям всех контроллеров

Tags: php, yii2, access-control

Есть BaseController, в нем правила доступа вида

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                  // We will override the default rule config with the new AccessRule class
                  'ruleConfig' => [
                    'class' => AccessRule::className(),
                  ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    // 'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],

                    // 'actions' => ['index'],
                    'controllers' => ['user'],
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                  // 'controllers' => ['site'],
                  // 'actions' => ['index', 'signup', 'login', 'error'],
                  'allow' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Все остальные контроллеры наследуются от него, т.е. к примеру

```
class UserController extends BaseController
```

Как разрешить доступ всем ролям ко всем действиям всех контроллеров, но если контроллер User, разрешить доступ только роли admin ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо переопределить behaviors конкретно для `UserController`.

BaseController.php:

```
class BaseController extends Controller 
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

UserController.php:

```
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            // We will override the default rule config with the new AccessRule class
            'ruleConfig' => [
                'class' => AccessRule::className(),
            ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

Т.е `BaseController` должен содержать общие фильтры/ограничения для все контроллеров, которые от него наследуются.

**UPDATE**

Если обраться к [исходникам yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/AccessRule.php#L131), то можно заметить, что матчинг контроллера происходит по свойству `Controller::$uniqueId`. Далее, смотрим в исходники Controller.php, где присутсвует [метод `Controller::getUniqueId()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L321). id контроллера определяется в зависимости от используемого модуля (к примеру, если ваше приложение разделено на frontend (то что видет пользователь), backend (админка) и т.д.). Я не знаю какой у вас модуль, наверно дефолтный (`Application`), потому "решение в лоб" - переопределяем `getUniqueId()`:

```
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function getUniqueId()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

Если всё же дефолтный, то достаточно указать свойство `Controller::$id`:

```
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public $id = 'user';
}
```

Далее в `BaseController` ваше `'controllers' => ['user']` должно сработать.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'ruleConfig' => [
                    'class' => AccessRule::className(),
                ],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'controllers' => ['user'],
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'controllers' => ['user'],
                        'allow' => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно конечно, но хотелось бы делать это в одном месте все

Comment: @Простогость: Это неверно с точки зрения архитектуры приложения. BaseController должен содержать общие правила, а не быть раздутым ([Fat Stupid Ugly Controllers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B8.D0.B1.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B5_.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BE.D1.88.D0.B8.D0.B1.D0.BA.D0.B8)). Если общих правил нет, то и создавать BaseController нет необходимости.

Comment: В том то и дело, что правила общие для всех, кроме контроллера User. Насчет раздутости, как же тогда DRY ? Получается что в каждом контроллере нужно прописывать одно и тоже ?

Интересно что так работает


`'controllers' => ['user'],
  'roles' => ['@', '?'],
  'allow' => false,`


Т.е. если пойти от обратного

Comment: @Простогость: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Простогость: Мне необходимо воспроизвести кокретно ваш сценарий, а пока я могу лишь вас направить в какую сторону копать. Все остальные actions контроллера UserController необходимо запретить использовать пользователям, которые не имеют роли `admin`. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не изменилось, так работает, добавил в `UserController`

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
      'access' => [
          'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                // We will override the default rule config with the new AccessRule class
                'ruleConfig' => [
                  'class' => AccessRule::className(),
                ],
          'rules' => [
              [
                  'allow' => true,
                  'roles' => ['admin'],
              ],
          ],
      ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, это надо внести в вопрос.

Comment: @Просто гость: Конечно будет + верно с точки зрения архитектуры приложения - логика конкретного контроллера (в данном случае action-правила) должна находится в самом контроллере. Собственно, об этом я уже вам писал. Да, и Qwerty прав. Данное уточнее стоит написать в вопросе. Кроме того, оно дублирует мой ответ.